# Which service account to use to connect from GKE to cloud SQL?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, google-iam

I'm following the instructions on how to connect from GKE to Cloud SQL: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine

It talks about YOUR-GSA-NAME. Google cloud creates "Compute Engine default service account" by default. Should I pick this one or create another service account for GKE only? What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compute Engine default service account won't be able to connect to Cloud SQL out of the box, you'll have to add permissions to it (Cloud SQL Client role) for it to be able to connect.

I would create a new one however, as you likely don't want all GCE instances to be able to connect to Cloud SQL, and for permissions, best practice is to limit access. So just create a new SA (service account) with the Cloud SQL Client role (and any other permissions you might need GKE to access) and use that one.

This is all found in IAM -> Service Accounts in the console.